# Stripe custom checkout not Posting

Tags: javascript, php, post, stripe-payments

Can anyone assist as to why this is not posting to booking/charge upon completion of input to the checkout pop up window?

The simple checkout example posts fine, I am new to js so I don't quite understand the flow of the commands.

```
<form action="/booking/charge" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
 <script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxx',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'xxxx',
    email: "test@test.com",
    description: '2 widgets',
    currency: 'gbp',
    amount: 350
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>    
</form>
```

Comment: Please, ask one question per post, it makes difficult to answer multiple questions in a single thread. What is the problem with that code exactly?

Comment: @Eduard Malakhov After completion of the input to the checkout pop up, the pop up closes and returns back to the same page, not completing the post to the booking/charge page as I believe it should do.  When I had the script for the simple checkout inside the form tags, after completion of the input to the checkout pop it completes the post to booking/charge.  I don't understand why it does not with the custom checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that has worked for me (must include script for jQuery in header not footer)

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="message" value="Hello, world"/></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="amount" value="10.00" /></p>
   <p><button type="submit" id="customButton">Pay</button></p>
</form>
<script> 
// checkout handler
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '<YOUR PUBLIC KEY>',
    image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    token: function(token) {
        /* Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
         You can access the token ID with `token.id`
         Pass along various parameters you get from the token response
         and your form.*/                    
        var myData = {
                token: token.id,
                email: token.email,
                amount: Math.round($("#amount").val() * 100),
                message: $("#message").val()
        };
        /* Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
           change the first parameter to your charge script*/
        $.post("<YOUR ROUTE TO charge.php", myData,function (data) {
            // if you get some results back update results
            $("#myForm").hide();
            $(".results").html("Your charge was successful");
        }).fail(function () {
            // if things fail, tell us
            $(".results").html("I'm sorry something went wrong");
        })
    }
});
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
        name: 'Stripe.com',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        description: '2 widgets',
        amount: Math.round($("#amount").val() * 100)
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Hope this is of help to someone, experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the custom Checkout integration, you need to do a little more work. You write your own code to handle the token returned by Stripe. This is all done within `token` callback.

Here's a traditional form submission example, it uses JQuery, appends the token and user's email as values to hidden form elements, then submits the form.

```
function (token) {
  // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
  $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
  $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
  $("#myForm").submit();
}
```

**Full Example: https://jsfiddle.net/osrLsc8m/**

Alternatively, you could submit the data to your backend with an AJAX request.

```
function (token) {        
  var myData = {
   token: token.id,
   email: token.email
   };

   /* 
    Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
    change the first parameter to your charge script
   */
   $.post("/echo/html/",myData,function(data){ ... });
}
```

**Full Example: http://jsfiddle.net/742tety5/**

Comment: thanks @duck I couldn't get the code in example 1 working, but I changed the  $('#customButton').on('click', function (e)   to document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) and same for close checkout function.  Do you know why the '.on' functions do not seem to be working?  Also I have had no luck with the Ajax alternative...maybe related to functions not performing same as in example 1...thankyou again for your help

Comment: I got the first example working by moving the jQuery include to the header from the footer in my code, so thanks for the tip, does this sound correct to you?

Ajax version simply refreshing page still, appending url with a '?'

Comment: ...update...need the <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script> above the form tags still to get the second example showing checkout pop up.