# how to pass the stripe checkout token in a thenable manner

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe checkout api to capture user credit card info for creating a stripe customer and a subscription. In my ngOnInit I am initializing the api popup handler:

```
this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: stripePubKey,
          image:  '../../assets/images/logo.png',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: token => token;
          }
         });
   }
```

and then calling it like this which doesn't work but I want to pass on the token to the next function which includes update the db:

```
this.handler.open({
                     name: 'Test',
                     excerpt: 'Sample ....',
                     amount: 1000
                  }).then((token) => {
```

The popular way to do this is to send the request to the backend in the ngOnInit. I am just not comfortable with making a call from ngOnInit to do all this work which include creating the customer and subscription on Stripe. How can I configure this so that this.handler.open is thenable?

Comment: Take a look to this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-stripe-checkout

Comment: Is `handler.open()` not synchronous? Promisifying it only makes sense if it is asynchronous. As far as I can tell, the token exposed by `StripCheckout.configure()` (more spefically `token.id`) is typically set as the value of a hidden form field. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42142780/3478010), for example.

Comment: @Roamer-1888  StripeCheckout.configure() has a callback where  the token is accessible. What I am concern about is conducting all the remaining operations to create a subscription in that callback which is in ngOnInit.   I need a better way of doing this.

Comment: @Jaime This looks promising (pun intended) but I am not sure I can use it in production!

Comment: @MichaelE, I'm not sure I share your concern. But assuming there's some merit in it, if you conduct the remaining operations somewhere other than the ngOnInit callback then `token.id` needs to be made available to some handler that fires in response to some later event, in which case the id can't be passed through; it needs to be stored.  Your design options are to store the id in the DOM, in a closure, in a cookie or in local storage. As far as I can tell, the standard approach is for the callback to which the token is revealed to store `token.id` in a hidden form field.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this problem in 2023, you can solve it like this:

```
makePayment() {
   let self = this;
   this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: stripePubKey,
          image:  '../../assets/images/logo.png',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (stripeToken: any) {
            console.log(stripeToken);
           console.log("Stripe token generated!");
           self.createCharge(stripeToken.id);
          }
         });
   }
   this.handler.open({
     name: 'Test',
     excerpt: 'Sample ....',
     amount: 1000
   });
}

createCharge(stripeToken) {
    let checkoutBody = {
      token = stripeToken,
    }
    
    this.paymentService.createCharge(checkoutBody)
    .subscribe(
      {
        next: (v) => console.log(v),
        error: (e) => console.log(e)
      }
    );
}
```